# What is wrong with this code involving a large number?

Tags: warning-messages, debugging

Below is my code:

```
n = 15;
roots = Table[Sqrt[Prime[i]], {i, n}];
q = 10^125;
error = N[Abs[q*roots - Round[q* roots]], 12]
```

Here I have a large number q = 10^125. It is okay for other calculations (which I did not show). But because of it, I get

[image]

So, where did it go wrong? My OS is windows 7 and my version is 11. I am actually often confused by the operation N. When should I use it? Before any other operation or after all other operators?

Comment: Try this `error = Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 400}, 
  N[Abs[q*roots - Round[q*roots]], 12]]`

Comment: It works. But why is not an issue in other cases. The number q is used many times in other lines.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting questions. This is a special tag that is meant to be added by someone else than the original poster after the bug has been verified by the community.

Comment: BTW this is not a bug. The red box is a warning that the results have no effective precision left in them.